# How to make python wait for it's turn (tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Right now the code executes executes the following "if statement" under the computer_move function *. I want it to wait for the player to click another button. Right now, the code places the x before the player clicks a button to place an "o".

```
import tkinter as tk

board = tk.Tk()

def player_move(widget):
    if widget["o"] not in ("o", "x"):
        widget["text"] = "o"
        widget["state"] = "disabled"
        computer_move()

def computer_move():
    if i["text"] == "Open Space":
        i["text"] = "x"
        i["state"] = "disabled"
    else:
        c["text"] = "x"
        c["state"] = "disabled"
    if a["text"] and c["text"] == "x" or "o": # *
        b["text"] = "x"
        b["state"] = "disabled"

board.geometry("400x500")
board.title("Board")

buttons = []

a = tk.Button(board, text="x", state = "disabled")
a["command"] = lambda x=a:player_move(x)
a.grid(row=0, column = 0)
buttons.append(a)

board.mainloop()
```

Comment: code doesn't executes `if` statemante - you set `x` and disable button using  `Button(board, text="x", state = "disabled")` and program can't executes event `computer_move()` when you click button.

Comment: what do you try to do in `if a["text"] and c["text"] == "x" or "o": # *` ? It checks  `if ( a["text"] ) and ( c["text"] == "x" ) or ( "o" ):`

Comment: what do you try to do with `widget["o"]` ? `widget` doesn't have property "o", it has property "text" - `widget["text"]` - which may have value `"o"` or `"x"` (or other)

Comment: I ask - what result do you expect with code `if a["text"] and c["text"] == "x" or "o": # *` ? and what result do you expect with code `widget["o"]` ?

Comment: I want to make it so if buttons a, b and c both say "x", then the computer wins the game of ti tac toe.

Comment: BTW, I made those if statements in a certain way on purpose.  I do not want   a the computer to put the "x" at random

Answer (score 1):

Code doesn't set `x` but you do it in line

```
 a = tk.Button(board, text="x", state= "disabled")
```

so remove `text="x", state="disabled"`

---

BTW:

`widget["o"]` is incorrect - button doesn't have property with name `"o"`.
It has property `"text"` - `widget["text"]` - which may have value `"o"` or `"x"`

`if a["text"] and c["text"] == "x" or "o":` is rather incorrent. Especially

```
c["text"] == "x" or "o"
```

It has to be

```
c["text"] == "x" or c["text"] == "o"
```

or

```
c["text"] in ("x", "o")
```

I think you try to do

```
if a["text"] in ("x", "o") and c["text"] in ("x", "o"):
```

It is better to keep button on list - you can use `for` loop to check all buttons in `computer_move`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def player_move(btn):
    # if button is empty 
    if btn["text"] not in ("o", "x"):
        # then set `o` and disable button 
        btn["text"] = "o"
        btn["state"] = "disabled"
        # and make comuter move
        computer_move()

def computer_move():
    # check all buttons 
    for btn in buttons:
        # if button is empty 
        if btn["text"] not in ("o", "x"):
            # then set `x` and disable button 
            btn["text"] = "x"
            btn["state"] = "disabled"
            # and skip checking other buttons
            break

# --- main ---

board = tk.Tk()

board.geometry("400x500")
board.title("Board")

buttons = []

for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        btn = tk.Button(board, width=1)
        btn["command"] = lambda x=btn:player_move(x)
        btn.grid(row=row, column=col)
        buttons.append(btn)

board.mainloop()
```